# What is a good free / open source cross platform mobile application development framework

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cross-platform, windows-phone

I am looking for a good cross platform mobile application development framework that at least supports the big 4: iOS,Android,Windows Phone and Blackberry.

Can you please also let me know what is the best points of the framework you recommend?

Comment: FWIW, I don't think you will ultimately find something that meets your fancy. The various platforms are different enough not only in coding styles but also in look and feel. My experience is that there really isn't a good end-all be-all solution..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[PhoneGap](http://Phonegap.com) is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native applications with web technologies and get access to APIs and app stores"

Check about the supported features by OS [here](http://www.phonegap.com/about/features)

- You can use your javascript , HTML, CSS skills to create native apps. avoiding the burden of Java (Android), ObjectiveC (iOS) etc.
- Free!

[This](http://Appcelerator.com) is another strong contender.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but Appcelerator is not free/Open source. Phonegap compiles seem confusing but signed up for the beta. Going to look into it a bit more, +1 for the suggested answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to suggest you [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) for your needs. It supports almost 6 platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on the [link](http://mobiledevices.about.com/od/mobileappbasics/tp/Top-5-Tools-Multi-Platform-Mobile-App-Development.htm) this will help you

Comment: hmm, will look into those, http://rhomobile.com/ looks very interesting.